# wp_enqueue_script not loading script (wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom script via my functions.php file.

Here is the code. First I am loading jQuery and then the script

When I view my source code I can not see a link to the script.

*By the way, let me know if you need to see more of my code I wasn't sure how much I should post.*

```
// jQuery
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

// show Hide
function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'show-hide', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/show-hide.js', 
    array('jquery')
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

to hook `add_my_script()` function on to action.